# React-S3 blocked by CORS policy

Tags: reactjs, express, amazon-s3, cors

So I am using `React-S3` in order to upload a file from my react app to S3 Bucket. I am using a proxy server but still is giving me the following error

`Access to fetch at 'https://atlantic-files.s3.amazonaws.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:5000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

This is my server

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "Content-Type");
    next();
});

app.get('/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html'), function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    })
})

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(5000);


console.log('App is listening on port 5000');
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try cors on the route whom you want to enable cors.
https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "Content-Type");
    next();
});

app.get('/*',function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build/index.html'), function (err) {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err)
        }
    })
})

app.get('/', cors(), function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(5000);


console.log('App is listening on port 5000');
```

Comment: @MarkusHayner , sorry I put cors middle at the wrong route. I have edited it. try now